# Why was this man not charged with this offence that it seems he has committed?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, sentencing

I was reading this article, [Man jailed after sending photos of his genitals to undercover police officer](http://www.itv.com/news/wales/2016-02-04/man-jailed-after-sending-photos-of-his-genitals-to-undercover-police-officer/).

This article states:

> Malcolm Blount, 55, was caught by police after he emailed three pictures of his genitals to an officer posing as the 12-year-old girl.

He was arrested for a few offenses but NOT Causing a child to watch a sexual act (Section 12 of the Sexual Offenses Act 2003). If you look at the [Sexual Offences
Definitive Guideline](http://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/Final_Sexual_Offences_Definitive_Guideline_content_web1.pdf)

One would think category 3 would apply. Perhaps I am not clear on what "Sexual activity" in the legal sense means. Would this boil down to the genital being erect or flaccid? There has been a recent provision to Section 67 of the serious crime Act (2015), called [sexual communications with a child (2017)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/604931/circular-commencement-s67-serious-crime-act-2015.pdf).

which he would have been charged with, but the offense was committed in 2016.

In this instance, what constitutes a bare minimum of sexual activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was no actual child who was caused to view the material, so there was no offense under that provision.

By contrast, inciting a child under 13 to engage in sexual activity is an [inchoate offense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoate_offense), so it is not necessary for any harm to an actual victim to have occurred.  Note that the relevant section of the [Sexual Offenses Act 2003](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/contents) concerns "causing or inciting," and that the charge was "inciting."  The section concerning watching a sexual act, by contrast, only inludes "causing."

Comment: Jesus, that seems like such a simple error to make! thanks for pointing that out.